# Why can I call external files, but not internal files?

Tags: javascript, css, apache

I have Apache 2.2, under Centos, and I have this problem:

I have an simple HTML file.  If I call a CSS or Javascript library/file from an external source,  like Jquery, I have not problems.  BUT, if this file or library is into the own machine, then my browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc). do not recognize it.

**testing.html:**

```html
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> 
    <title>Hello</title> 
</head> 

<body> 
<h1>Hello</h1> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**styles.css:**

```css
h1 {color:blue;font-size:70px;text-align:center;color:gray;}
```

I have reviewing users and access levels, and all Ok.  I agree your comments and suggestions.

Comment: is the css file stored in the same folder as your html file?

Comment: Hi @JoshHarold, yes, same folder

Comment: it worked just fine for me, check the naming of your CSS document.

Comment: @JoshHarold the name of file is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, adding this lines to .htaccess:

ForceType application/x-httpd-php
    Header set Content-Type "application/javascript"


    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
    Header set Content-Type "text/css"

Regards

Comment: Do you mean that the reason behind this is the server configuration ?